# Computing rendered property of xp:messages control

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

On my xpage I have an xp:messages for which I have adapted the UI to Boostrap/corporate standard.

Therefor I have placed the control inside a xp:panel control.

I wonder how I could compute the rendered property of this panel based upon if the xp:messages control has any items in it or not. I could not find an answer on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you display inside the message component an error, you can check the FacesContext.getMessage()

For more details see the answer, [Get error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939060/get-error-messages)

Comment: I used the facesContext.getMessages().hasNext(). Thank you for your answer.